# MySQL how to query complex relational tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables:

[image]

I want to show an article where its subject related term is 'milk'.

subject_catalog table dictionary:

```
index_key = primary key
subject = takes any words
rt_key = serves as 'related term' foreign key to its own.
```

sample data for subject_catalog:

```
|index_key|subject|rt_key|
|------------------------|
|  1      | tea   | null |
|  2      | milk  | 1    |
|------------------------|
```

sample data for article:

```
|article_key|title     |pages|
|----------------------------|
|  1        | article_1| 5   |
|  2        | article_2| 3   |
|----------------------------|
```

sample data for article_subject:

```
|article_key|index_key|
|---------------------|
|  1        | 1       |
|---------------------|
```

here is my trial query but it wont show any article:

```
SELECT
    `article`.`title`
FROM
    `article_subject`
    INNER JOIN `article` 
        ON (`article_subject`.`article_key` = `article`.`article_key`)
    INNER JOIN `subject_catalog` 
        ON (`article_subject`.`index_key` = `subject_catalog`.`index_key`)
    INNER JOIN `subject_catalog` AS `subject_catalog_1` 
        ON (`subject_catalog_1`.`rt_key` = `subject_catalog`.`index_key`)
WHERE `subject_catalog_1`.`subject` LIKE 'milk%'
```

Comment: just whant to say: ¡Thanks for giving the relation of your tables like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT article.title
FROM article_subject
    LEFT JOIN article USING (article_key)
    LEFT JOIN subject_catalog USING (index_key)
    LEFT JOIN subject_catalog sc2 ON subject_catalog.index_key = sc2.rt_key
WHERE subject_catalog.subject LIKE 'milk%' OR sc2.subject LIKE 'milk%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d5f5/3/0

Comment: You have no result because the milc entry has not the right index for any article subject

Comment: I have enhanced the fiddle and added a row in article_subject to show you haw to get a result. The Query is correct.

Comment: milk doesn't need to be placed in article_subject because its rt_key is linked to tea. I want to use 'milk' to show 'article_1' w/o adding another entry to article_subject. Adding an entry to article_subject linking 'article_1' and 'milk' directly will kill the purpose of this question :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.title from article A inner Join article_subject S 
On A.article_key =S.article_key inner join subject_catalog C 
on C.index_key = C.index_key where C.rt_key =1
```

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89658/1)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry no result either :(

Comment: @borj Milk related to subject or does subject starts with this word `Milk` ?

Comment: 'milk' is related to subject 'tea' and 'tea' is linked to 'article_1' trough article_subject table. I want to use 'milk' to show 'article_1'.

Comment: @borj Sorry it's in Sql Server .